# ImageView source always overrides its background Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to set one side rounded to an ImageView

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sofT.png)

So, I have added this as background to ImageView

one_rounded_side.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="200.0"
android:viewportHeight="100.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#000"
    android:pathData="M200,0H0v4.5h0v75.8h0c17.8,10.2 56,17.2 100.5,17.2c44.5,0 81.6,-7 99.5,-17.2h0V4.5h0V0z" />
```

And setting the images to ImageView at runtime, but the image I set always overrides this background drawable. So it displays like normal rectangle.

I have added ImageView like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/one_rounded_side"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

I have tried by setting background programmatically after adding image at runtime also, but it didn't worked.

Can anyone please help me to find out solution?

Comment: To show a rounded Image  you need to create a Rounded `Bitmap`. How are you setting Image ? If you are using `Glide` or `Picasso` then you can user `Transformation` on load .

Comment: Imageview does not have any id ?

Comment: @Tarul use image.setClipToOutline(true) in your activity

Comment: @AmanRawat It didn't worked

Comment: @ADM I just want to have bottom side rounded with rectangular base. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @ADM try android:foreground="@drawable/one_rounded_side" intead of background else you will have to make your customImageView. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @AmanRawat setting drawable to foreground is showing the rounded cut on Image, but image is still displaying in rectangle

Comment: @Tarul It might be that your image is rectangular. try scaling your image . Use android:scaleType="centerCrop" or android:scaleType="fitXY".

Comment: @AmanRawat i am not OP of this question . If you have a solution post it as answer with output .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution. This worked perfect for me.

Include below code in your project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

Include below code in app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.developer-shivam:Crescento:1.2.1'
```

Include this in your xml file

```
<developer.shivam.crescento.CrescentoContainer
    android:id="@+id/crescentoContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    attribute:curvature="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_news_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</developer.shivam.crescento.CrescentoContainer>
```

And set image to ImageView at runtime.

Reference: https://github.com/developer-shivam/Crescento